# Having an issue with 3 conditions using php ternary

Tags: php

Im having an error on this php ternary with 3 conditions and Im not understanding why its not working, do you see the error?

```
 $level = ($user['level'] == '1' 
             ? 'Admin' 
             : ($user['level'] == '2' 
                       ? 'Editor' 
                       : ($user['level'] == '3' 
                                ? 'Premium' )));
```

Comment: Don't nest ternary operators like that. If I had to maintain that code I'd find you and .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's ternary operator [is left associative instead of right associative](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61915). This makes it very hard to properly nest, and most experienced developers would recommend against it.

Here's the example from the bug report linked above:

> ### Test script:
>
> ```
> $arg = "3";
> $food = (  ($arg == '1') ? 'Banana' :
>            ($arg == '2') ? 'Apple' :
>            ($arg == '3') ? 'Toast' :
>            ($arg == '4') ? 'Cantalope' :
>            ($arg == '5') ? 'Swiss Cheese' : 'Fig Newton Cookie'
>        );
> echo $food;
> ```
>
> ### Expected result:
>
> I expected to see 'Toast'.
>
> ### Actual result:
>
> The actual result is 'Swiss Cheese'.

Instead of nested ternary, use `if`, `then`, `else` or a [`switch` statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Answer (score 2):

Don't nest ternary statements, it's poor practice and hard to debug.

Your far right ternary statement is missing half of it:

```
($user['level'] == '3' ? 'Premium' )
```

This is invalid, you need the `else` part. Try:

```
 $level = ($user['level'] == '1' ? 'Admin' : ($user['level'] == '2' ? 'Editor' : ($user['level'] == '3' ? 'Premium' : 'Invalid' )));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a last `else`.

Let's format the ternary properly and see where this leads us:

```
 $level = 
    ($user['level'] == '1' ? 
        'Admin' : 
    ($user['level'] == '2' ?
        'Editor' :
    ($user['level'] == '3' ?
        'Premium' )));
```

Essentially, you're saying, 1 is admin, 2 is editor, and 3 is premium. But you missed what 4, or anything else would be.

You require:

```
 $level = 
    ($user['level'] == '1' ? 
        'Admin' : 
    ($user['level'] == '2' ?
        'Editor' :
    ($user['level'] == '3' ?
        'Premium' : 'Another user level'
    )));
```

However, I honestly think you should just switch this or keep all values in an array and do this instead:

```
$levels = ['Admin', 'Editor', 'Premium'];
$level = $levels[intval($user['level']) - 1];
```

Comment: Thank you, but I dont want that 'Another user level', and Im always trying to remove it and I have always the same error! But maybe its better use your array solution instead! thanks!

Comment: You can check if your user level is within the range of the array (namely positive and not above `count($levels)`).